# PHP mysql max table fields

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

Is it okay if I have a table with more than 20 fields in DB table?

```
ID | NAME | 1 | 2 | 3 | .....
```

Each of fields like '2' holds only Y or N in them.
Or is it bad idea to have so maybe fields in one table?
Will this slow down my performance of server?

And there may be about 20 or more Ids in the table.

Comment: yes its ok, just make index for each field you use after where clause

Comment: Can you give some context, why would you want the Y/N below a list of numbers, do the numbers correspond to questionnaire fields or something?

Comment: @Liam Bailey I do it so i can check which name can acces certain page. If name FOO can acces page 2 then there will be Y. I need it to be easy to manage who can view it. If there is more than one table for this it will be hard. Best would be for example: ID | NAME | Y-PAGES | And then just put page numbers in there 2,3,etc. But it will be harder to get them out to check right?

Comment: @mypoint I have given an answer with how I would achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea if it will slow the database down but it is not a very nice database design, no. What you could do to optimize the design is the following:

Make a table: `ID | NAME` and another table: `ID | NUMBER | BOOLEAN` and link the two ID's together.

You will probably have some more PHP code this way, but it will make the database a lot more managable and neater.

Comment: wouldnt it be better if I for example made the table like this:
ID | NAME | Y    |
2  | foo  | 2,3,5|

Then just select the numbers where is Y instead of making each number seperate field.

Comment: That's possible too, yeah. It depends if you need only booleans (yes/no or 1/0) or if you want to have other ID's like strings too. If you don't need strings, storing a few rows with only an ID and a boolean takes less space than storing multiple integers, seperated by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

It's much better if you make additional table

table `names`:

```
name_ID |   name
  1        george
  2        jenny
```

table `acl`:

```
acl_ID |   name_ID  |  page_ID | acccess
   1          1          1          Y
   2          1          2          N
```

table `pages`:

```
 page_ID | page_name
    1        Page1
    2        Page2
```

Getting results is very easy

```
SELECT
  names.name,
  pages.page_name,
  acl.access
FROM names
LEFT JOIN acl ON acl.name_ID = names.name_ID
LEFT JOIN pages ON pages.page_ID = acl.page_ID
WHERE
   acl.page_ID=1 AND    # or.. pages.page_name='Page1'
   names.name = 'george'
```

will give you..

```
 name  | page_name | acccess
george     Page1        Y
```

- one row for each page
- one row for each `name` (whatever it is)
- one row for each setting. (access Y/N)

Comment: well its made so for example to check if NAME can acces page 2. I dont want to make table for each page. Also so i could easily manage which name can view page and which cant.

Comment: @mypoint you need to make create one row for each page. I updated my answer. If you are going to use only numbers for page, table `pages` is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in this case would be have one table with the columns, ID, Name, Pages and store a serialized array of the pages the user can open in the Pages field. In PHP the pages John can open would be like

```
$pagesj = array(2,4,6,7,9)
```

;

To store them in the DB you do:

```
$dbpages = serialize($pagesj);
//insert $dbpages string into db for user John
```

Then to check if John can open a given page you would simply do:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb","user","pass");
$q = "SELECT Pages from mytable WHERE User = $user";
$pages = $conn->query($q)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
$allowed_pages = unserialize($pages);
if (in_array($currentpage,$allowed_pages))
{
//user can view page
}
else {
//can't
}
```

The important bit is the unserialize and in_array, you can use your own way of running the query, as I have never used PDO::FETCH_COLUMN before and I am not sure if the above works as intended, but the idea is to get at the seralized pages data as quickly as possible, unserialize it, then check if the page is in there.

This is how I would do it personally, although to be honest I can't see me ever doing what you are doing (allowing certain users to view certain pages) in this way, I would probably have user groups, or access areas or some such.